# SysUser inheritance in MDriven

Tags: mdriven

I am wondering if I could/should use inheritance to the SysUser class to model types of users or do I "mess up" the inherent functionality tied to the SysUser class then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SysUser is part of the ASP.NET Identity implementation in MDriven Turnkey. As such we look for a matching SysUser when a user logs in (via forms or via federated login).

You should not subclass, or remove it (same for all Sys...-classes).
You can add attributes and associations.

Consider adding a UserType class tag SysUsers with one or many of these with an association.